# VB.net Disable weekends and future calendar dates

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, calendar

I've been trying my best to find some code examples on how to disable the datetimepicker dates in the future and also all the weekend dates but i am unable to find any! Only thing i can find is ASP.net code.

If anyone knows how to do this in VB then please do share! :o)

Thanks,

David

Comment: VB.Net or VB6? There is no DTPicker control in .Net. Do you mean the [VB6 DatetimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276346%28VS.60%29.aspx) or the   [VB.Net DateTimepicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276346%28VS.60%29.aspx) or the [MonthCalendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.aspx)-Control?

Comment: I found [this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/073c331e-3958-4b6a-8113-e928fedc5645/vbnet-datetimepicker-grayout-or-disable-specific-dates-not-min-max?forum=vbgeneral) helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Set the DateTimePicker.MaxDate property.  You'll have to reject weekend days by validating the user's selection.  Use the DateTime.DayOfWeek property.